# extract the total count line (wc -l) number in shell

Tags: shell, wc

I am trying to figure out how to extract the last total count number when I use "wc -l" on multiple files under a directory. For example:

```
currentDir$ wc -l *.fastq
    216272 a.fastq
    402748 b.fastq
   4789028 c.fastq
  13507076 d.fastq
   5818620 e.fastq
  24733744 total
```

I would only need to extract 24733744 from the above. I tried

```
wc -l *.fastq | tail -l
```

to get

```
  24733744 total
```

but not sure what to do next. If I use "cut", the annoying thing is that there are multiple spaces before the number, and I will need to use this code for other folders too, and the number of spaces may differ.

Any advice is appreciated. Thank you very much!

Comment: Use `tr` to squeeze multiple spaces into a single space (https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/145981/8927), then `cut` away.

Comment: You could also use `awk '{print $1}'` to print only the first column of textual data.

Comment: Actually, that would be `wc -l *.fastq | awk 'END {print $1}'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this particular problem, it's probably easier to do :

```
cat *.fastq | wc -l
```

Comment: @JacobKrall, it does under Linux, `GNU Awk 4.1.3`, which variant are you using?

Answer (score 2):

This should work with any number of spaces:

```
wc -l *.fastq | tail -l |  tr -s ' ' | cut -f 2 -d ' '
```

Example:

```
    echo "  24733744 total" | tr -s ' ' | cut -f 2 -d ' '
24733744
```

Comment: Glad it helped! Have a nice day!